# Negative Lookahead & Negative Lookbehind to Exclude Alphanumeric characters surrounded by Quotation marks

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will distinguish between variable names and strings. Strings will be surrounded by quotation marks, and variable names will consist of alphanumeric characters and underscores. I am trying to match substrings within an entire line, so since `^` anchors to the start of a line and `$` anchors to the end of a line, I have avoided these two.

My issue for excluding certain variable names deals with my negative lookahead. It only applies to one character, and I want this rule to apply to the start of a substring too.

For example:

```
(?<!")([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*)(?!")
```

If this regular expression is given the string `Hello there`, it will come back with 2 matches, `Hello` and `there`. That is expected. However, if I add a quotation mark at the end of a substring, every character up until the one with a following quotation mark will still be returned as a match. For example, `Hello there"` will match `Hello` and `ther` with this regular expression. I guess that this makes sense as well given my first series in the middle group matches.

What is wrong with my groupings?

Comment: So you want  `(?<!")\b([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b(?!")`?

Comment: That is certainly closer to what I would like. Providing the string `"Hello there how are you"` will exclude `"Hello` and `you"` but it will match `there`, `how`, and `are`. What I am thinking about involves some sort of recursion to exclude everything in between or next to quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Basically the inverse of this solution https://regex101.com/r/W4qMDG/1

Comment: When you say "inverse", splitting comes to mind first. What is the programming language?

Comment: I am currently using Python 3.8.2

Comment: Does it mean you want to extract all green words here - https://regex101.com/r/u4cGMS/1? `re.findall(r''''[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|(\w+)''', text)`

Comment: Like https://ideone.com/QxyiSC?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are a genius!! This is almost exactly what I need. I will attempt to add in the prefix rules as well (i.e. a variable name should not start with a number)

Comment: This question would be easier to understand if you provided some examples of matching strings and strings that shouldn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
r"""'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\b([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b"""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJXNPP/1).

*Details*:

- `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - a single quoted string literal
- `|` - or
- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`  - a double quoted string literal
- `|` - or
- `\b([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b` - one or more letters or underscores and then zero or more alphanumeric chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QxyiSC):

```py
import re
rx = r"""'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\b([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b"""
text = r"""
Hello Colm "This is a test\\\\"
"This is also an NL test"
'And this has  an escaped quote don\'t  in it ' Blue Boy
"This has a single quote ' but doesn\' end the quote as it started with double quotes"

"line spanning with escaped quote at the end of a line\"
"

"Foo Bar" "Another Value" something else
"""
print(list(filter(None, re.findall(rx, text))))
# => ['Hello', 'Colm', 'Blue', 'Boy', 'something', 'else']
```